# JSON array does not get returned correctly to frontend

Tags: c#, json, kendo-ui

So I am trying to fetch some data from Dynamcis CRM and while that works fine I am struggling with reciving it correctly to frontend.

**What I expect**

Returned JSON correctly formatted to AJAX call
So in the picture below, instead of arrays in red rectangle, I want keys and values.

**What I get**

As you can see from the image below, many things are correctly (marked green) but the data is formatted wrong.
So it is correct that it is 37 objects, it is correct it is 8 subobjects. But each object is written wrong:
[image]

If I, in another case, sends it as string to frontend, copies that in to the console, it will format it correctly. Same if I copy the string from backend (before I send it) console will format string correctly. But sending it as JSON and it comes like the image above.

This is the code I am using to send to frontend. I did not include fetchxml because of size and because data is retrieved correctly.

```
        JArray crmItems = new JArray();
        JObject crmItem;

        using (var CrmSvc = new CrmConnectionManager())
        {
            EntityCollection OrdersList = CrmSvc.Connection.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchForSupplier));
            foreach (var item in OrdersList.Entities)
            {
                crmItem = new JObject();//Reset variable
                foreach (KeyValuePair<String, string> attribute in item.FormattedValues)
                {
                    crmItem.Add(new JProperty(attribute.Key, attribute.Value));
                }
                crmItems.Add(crmItem);
            }
        }

        return Json(new { status = "success", result = crmItems } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is the JSON I get returned. When it is returned from Controller it is surrounded with ''. (as a string)

```
[
    {
        "contractvalue": "100",
        "type": "type1",
        "contractname": "name",
        "productid": "productname",
        "quantity": "0"
    },  
    {
        "contractvalue": "100",
        "type": "type1",
        "contractname": "name",
        "productid": "productname",
        "quantity": "0"
    },  
    {
        "contractvalue": "100",
        "type": "type1",
        "contractname": "name",
        "productid": "productname",
        "quantity": "0"
    }
]
```

Comment: show you JSON please

Comment: I now have added to the question

Comment: I would suggest you to use JSON.net to deserialise your json string to c# object and then you can work on this object